# More information in array php

Tags: php

At this moment i have an array that looks like this

```
array ( 
[0] => player0 

[1] => player1

[2] => player2 
)
```

the rows are variable between 2 and 15.

I want to add extra information in the array, like this;

```
array ( 
[0] => player0
    => 1

[1] => player1
    => 1     

[2] => player2 
    => 1
)
```

Is this possible?

I tried multiple things with foreach, loops and array_push.
But I can't get the extra information in the array

Thank you for your time.

Comment: one key one value, one key cannot have multi value in an array.

Comment: Is it possible to make from 1 array an array within an array?

Comment: how can I make a multidimensional array from this array?

Comment: @HindrikVonk what is `1` meaning here? is that meaning that is the player is going to play then 1 if not then 0, something like that?

Comment: just simply use a humble foreach each, and you can either change the current or transfer it to a new one

Comment: How about this structure? `$players = [['player0',1],['player1',1],['player2',1],];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make it a multidimensional array. Since the second dimension is not uniform data, it should be an associative array, e.g.

```
[
    ['name' => 'player1', 'score' => 1],
    ['name' => 'player2', 'score' => 3],
    ['name' => 'player3', 'score' => 2]
]
```